# How to parse Json response using JavaScript and populate field with specific data from the response

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I will start with, I am not strong in javascript but I am learning Javascript while taking a course. I am running into an issue ... I am trying to get the user first name and last name in a drop-down list based on the search the user provided. I was able to get the drop down to populate but I cannot seem to be able to parse the object to an actual string. I get the following results back:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Can any javascript expert help me resolve this?

Here is my JSON response

```
{  
"users":[  
  {  
     "first_name":"khemlall",
     "last_name":"mangal",
     "image":{  
        "url":"https://chymeinuserupload.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/image/1/KDFM_062.jpg"
     },
     "url":"/users/1"
  },
  {  
     "first_name":"Donald",
     "last_name":"trump",
     "image":{  
        "url":"https://chymeinuserupload.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/image/2/2018-02-28_11_53_35-Step_2_of_4__Select_a_Logo_Design___LogoMaker_Customer_Service.png"
     },
     "url":"/users/2"
  },
  {  
     "first_name":"Renita",
     "last_name":"mangal",
     "image":{  
        "url":"https://chymeinuserupload.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/image/3/20120426_food-1.jpg"
     },
     "url":"/users/3"
  },
  {  
     "first_name":null,
     "last_name":null,
     "image":{  
        "url":null
     },
     "url":"/users/4"
  },
  {  
     "first_name":null,
     "last_name":null,
     "image":{  
        "url":"https://chymeinuserupload.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/image/5/2018-03-27_09_48_19-new_version_chymin__1___2_.png_-_Windows_Photo_Viewer.png"
     },
     "url":"/users/5"
   }
  ]
 }
```

javascript code

```
  $(document).on('change', '#createcampaign_decisionmaker', function() {
    var input_state = $(this);
    console.log("khemlall starts")
    var decisionmaker = $("#decisionmaker");
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        decisionmaker.html("");
    } else {
        $.getJSON('/search/', function(data) {
            // cities_of_state.empty();
            var results = data;
            console.log( results);
            alert(data.users.first_name)
           // console.log(data.getValue("first_name"))

            var opt = '<option value="" selected="">list of user</option>';
            if (data.length == 0) {

            } else {

                 $.each(data, function(i, elm) {
                  console.log("loggo" + i);
                    opt += '<option>' + elm + '</option>';
                    decisionmaker.html(opt);
                    console.log('I' + i);

                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: try this: `$.each(data.users, function(index, value) {console.log("index" + index + ": " + value)})`

Comment: Hi Thank you, i still get the the object object as a result  khemlall starts
interest?createcampaign_id=187:369 {users: Array(5)}
interest?createcampaign_id=187:382 index0: [object Object]
interest?createcampaign_id=187:382 index1: [object Object]
interest?createcampaign_id=187:382 index2: [object Object]
interest?createcampaign_id=187:382 index3: [object Object]
interest?createcampaign_id=187:382 index4: [object Object]

Comment: ok this would work   console.log("index" + index + ": " + value.first_name)

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#createcampaign_decisionmaker', function() {
  var input_state = $(this);
  var decisionmaker = $("#decisionmaker");

  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    decisionmaker.html("");
  } else {
    $.getJSON('/search/', function(data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        var options = data.map(function(d) {
          return "<option value=\"" + d.url + "\">" + d.first_name + " " + d.last_name + "/<option>";
        });
        options.unshift("<option value=\"\" selected>list of users</option>");
        decisionmaker.html(options.join(""));
      } else {
        decisionmaker.html(""); // maybe indicate that there are no users if needed
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi i am not getting results to return with what you provided there. see below what i added, maybe you help me clean that up or update yours so i can understand the mapping piece. Do you mind advising me on how the mapping work? it just finding the element with that specific name that in the return json?

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to work for me, user3808826 I tried your code and it doesn't seem to return anything for me as the result

```
  $(document).on('change', '#createcampaign_decisionmaker', function() {
    var input_state = $(this);
    console.log("khemlall starts")
    var decisionmaker = $("#decisionmaker");
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        decisionmaker.html("");
    } else {
        $.getJSON('/search/', function(data) {
            var results = data;
            var opt = '<option value="" selected="">list of user</option>';
            if (results.length == 0) {

            } else {
                    //$.each(data.users, function(index, value)
                    //{console.log("index" + index + ": " + value)})
                 $.each(results.users, function(index, value) {

                    opt += '<option>'  + value.first_name + " " +  value.last_name + '</option>';
                    decisionmaker.html(opt);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```